# Cant find views/controller in published Azure app service

Tags: html, azure, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web site that is now published to my azure App service.

My problem is that when i try to visit my published verision of my site in the browser, I get a 404 for most of the views.

I have 3 different controllers:

- HomeController
- AdminController
- ExecutionController

All of the controllers have Actions, and the actions that returns a view is named exactly the same as my razor pages in these maps (NOTE: Executioncontroller is just for actions that doesn't return views.):

[image: Image of Home and Admin controllers views]

When I created the publish profile I right clicked on the project and choose `Publish`. Then I created the profile with these settings:

[image]

When I later on visited the Index view in the home controller witch is set as the home view everything was working fine, but after som clicking around I realized that some of the views just displays Chrome's default 404 page and says: `The site mysite.azurewebsites.net cant be found`. After trying to figure it out and a couple of publishes later, i cant even find: `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Home/Index` witch could be found before.

This is the General settings for the app service:

[image]

Here is for example the index action in the homecontroller thet returns a view:

[image]

And the view with the exact same name can be found in the Views/Home folder:

[image]

I enabled advanced logging for my app service and when i visit Home/Index action i get en Exception that says

```
2020-02-24 18:44:03.709 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'
```

Is it anybody that have had this problem to and is it someone that knows how to fix it?
I have searched a lot but never found someone with the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I get a 404 for most of the views`, Do you mean that some of these views could be accessed, but most of them return 404? Firstly, please check if you access the view page with correct URL. Besides, please share more information about your App service, such as, Runtime stack, Region etc that you specified. And please clarify detailed steps that you took to publish your project to Azure App service, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan No I mean that these views cant be found at all. But some of the views(actions inside controllers) can be found. More details will come.

Comment: You can make *"Remove additional files at destination"* option checked, then re-publish it and check if home/index can be accessed.

Comment: @FeiHan Wow thanks a lot! It worked. All the views can now be found. What does that option do? Remove some sort of cache files?

Comment: `All the views can now be found. What does that option do?` Hi @luddep, please check my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that some of the outdated/damaged files exist on web server (your app service), which cause the new publish not working well on your Azure app service.

And as we discussed in comments, making **"Remove additional files at destination"** option checked for a subsequent deployment to the same site, which would help delete the additional content available at the destination server (normally under app service `site\wwwroot` folder) that you have deleted in your project.